# export a large SQL file by mistake

Tags: export

I made a mistake by accidentially exported a large database (cloudSQL) of 20TB into SQL to a google bucket, it is currently running, I am afraid this bulky file will cost me a huge amount of money on google cloud and wish to stop this export, but there is no way I can stop this current export. Please help.
With the current error message,

> Exporting data to gs://.../bak/Cloud_SQL_Export_2023-02-17
> (15:55:15).sql. This may take a few minutes. While this operation is
> running, you may continue to view information about the instance.

I searched all the online tutorials, and try to contact google cloud, but found that I didn't purchase the support.

Comment: not a programming question

Comment: what was done finally to resolve this? update if any solution was found